# Best solution for fast insertion and searching in MySQL for large no. of rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, hadoop

We are planning to implement a feature in our web application which will provide users with the ability to do searches and save IDs of all matched records in DB (MySQL - INNODB) as a 'list'. Results can be in millions. We want users to be able to save up to 1 million ids. It has to be in real time (at max 5-10 secs delay is acceptable). This list can then be used later on as another filter in combination with the existing filters.

We don't need to pass these IDs from client side as the same search can be done on server side to retrieve those IDs. However, later on same search can't be reused to get those IDs as the search result can change.

We have few thousand active users and don't expect many to create such big lists but with passage of time total no. of ids saved in these lists can grow to hundreds of million.

Server has more RAM than the complete database (few hundred GBs). Also it uses a SSD.

Here are the issues we need to address:

```
- Saving up to 1 million ids in DB (within few secs)
- Using these IDs as a search criteria with other filters (this additional criteria shouldn't slow down the searches by more than few secs)
```

This is what seems to be some of the possible solutions:

Solution 1:

- Have a separate table with User Id, List Id, Doc Id
- Save IDs in a separate row (possibly 1 million rows for 1 list)
- Partition table after a certain size

Benefit: This table can easily be used later on in the JOIN condition and with indexes search performance should be fast.

Issue: Insertions would be slow - I know there are ways to speed up inserts but still it can take longer than few secs especially once the tables grows.

Solution 2:

- Save all IDs in one row
- Pass these IDs as IN parameter in the query in chunks using techniques like MapReduce for fast searching

Benefit: Insertions would be quite fast.

Issue: Search performance can be fast using MapReduce but it can put a lot of load on server especially if many users start doing such searches.

Any suggestions on what will be the best way? Are there any other possible approaches to cater to this scenario?

Comment: Would really appreciate if someone can comment on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194914/why-is-mysql-innodb-so-much-slower-at-full-table-scans-than-myisam

Comment: Is it mandatory to use MySQL?, coz you can use mongodb that will increase you read/write performance.

Comment: Its a big application which is already in MySQL so can't just shift to Mongodb because of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Saving intermediate results in progressive filtering -- I have never seen this used successfully.  Simply build the complete query and execute it each time.